# AccessViolationException - Trying to print

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, service, reporting

I am trying to print a report from Reporting Services, the approach I am taking is:

Render the report to get the Byte[]
Create a file in the client (Something.pdf)
Load that file in Read Mode to a FileStream
Then I try to make a call to the procedures described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us

If you in method SendBytesToPrinter, there is a line:
bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);

This line gives me the AccessVilationException.

Does anyone know how to solve this, and is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have memory allocation/manipulation problems, problably when allocating memory for the pBytes array. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/cf744c83-fd7e-434c-b160-3f076d7491bf for a similar problem that is solved in that thread.

Comment: Could you post some code that show us how you perform the allocation and initialization of the memory?